How to implement OAuth2.0 DPoP Authentication token in ASP.NET Core Web API?
I want to implement OAuth2.0 DPoP token in ASP.NET Core Web API. I have read the docs and blogs but as a beginner I am unable to get the things. If I get the full demonstration for implementing OAuth2.0 DPoP token in ASP.NET Core Web API it will be helpful. So I want the way to implement in visual studio 2022 with latest version of ASP.NET Core. Please help

Hi, this blog might be helpful. https://damienbod.com/2023/08/14/securing-apis-using-asp-net-core-and-oauth-2-0-dpop/

You would need to use client side Javascript to create the token as
https://github.com/udelt/dpop_js_test
I could not get Load runner to read the main.js but it works fine in visual studio
